# I have been trying to move /var to a new partition but the data disappears

Tags: linux, debian, partition, fstab, var

I have been attempting to move my /var folder to a new partition. I am using Debian 10.7 and have an 8GB processor so am trying to save space. I have tried several things but part of the data always seems to disappear. Here is what I have tried:

1. Create new partition /dev/sda7
2. mount /dev/sda7 to /mnt/newvar in /etc/fstab
3. boot into single user mode
4. mount / -rw -o remount
5. cp -arpPv /var/* /mnt/newvar (when I examine the /mnt/newvar folder, it is the same size as the /var folder so I assume the copy worked correctly, all folders appear to be there)
6. mv /var /var.old
7. mkdir /var
8. edit /etc/fstab and mount /dev/sda7 on /var
9. restart system

When the system comes up, several folders are not viewable in /var, but if I boot to a rescue USB I can see all the folders on /var from there.
Can I delete the /mnt/newvar folder? and the /var.old folder? If I do that then I seem to permanently lose the unviewable folders/files.
I wanted to move this folder to a new partition in order to make the rest of the system read-only and would like to conserve space. if I can't delete the old folders then using a different partition does not help much with that.
Can anyone tell me why some folders are not viewable and how do I keep from losing my data permanently?

Comment: In single user mode the /mnt/newvar directory won't have been mounted, so all you've done is copy the files from one part of the root filesystem to another

Comment: Any suggestions as to what I should do differently? This whole process confuses me because, as you have stated, all I did was copy from one part of the file system to another. I have followed several posts that state to do what I outlined, but maybe I am missing something. Can I do a move (mv) instead?

Comment: I've done this several times to move /home into its own partition. I've always booted from USB, created new [temporary] mount points for both the old and new locations. Worth running 'df -h' to check what is mounted where.

Comment: Instead of mounting in _/etc/fstab_, which is usually done only to have the partitions mounted by system on startup by `mount -a`, try directly mounting the partition by `mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/newvar`. Are there any errors in that command's output or `su -c dmesg | tail`? Does `mount | grep '/mnt/newvar'` show anything?

Answer (score 0):

Can you examine the symbolic links in `/var`? Because in some cases, the destination of these links is not a specific directory path but a relative one instead.

For example, the `/var/run/` points to `/run/`, which is the `/run` directory in `/`, but the destination of the link might be `../run/`, which is the `run` directory in the link's parent directory, which is still `root`.

But that also means that if you copy `/var/` to `/mnt/newvar/`, the system will find a directory named `run` in the parent directory of `newvar/`, which is `/mnt` when it encounters the link points to `../run/`.

With that being said, any operation that involves copying the `/var` might result in strange behaviours, so I suggest my solution: Mount the `/var` directly to your desired partition upon installation. As the result, your `/etc/fstab` may look like this

```
UUID=xxx /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
```

With xxx is the UUID of your desired partition and can be retrieved using the command `blkid`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/422794)

Answer (score -1):

The `/var` directory contains a couple of symbolic links:-

1. `/var/lock/` -> `/run/lock/`
2. `/var/run/`  -> `/run/`

I don't think that `cp` command is copying the symbolic links.

Perhaps you need to recreate them?

I wouldn't delete the old /var data until you have several days of trouble-free running.

Comment: `cp -a` absolutely copies symbolic links.

Comment: I also thought that the -P  is to copy symbolic links, but I could be misunderstanding the options for the cp command. Would a mv command work for this? And what would happen to the symbolic links using 'mv'?

Comment: `mv` moves symbolic links just fine. No idea what is your issue - I'm too lazy to understand it.

Comment: @newBird From `man cp`: _-a, --archive   same as -dR --preserve=all_; _-d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=links_. Thus, `-a` includes `-P`.